# Why the icon in QListWidget is displayed only for the first element?

Tags: c++, qt, qicon

**Target:** I want the class object inherited from QGraphicsItem to be displayed as an icon in QListWidget.

**Issue:** In the list, the icon is displayed only for the first item.

how it looks

[image]

Tried to redefine the function QIconEngine:: pixmap, put a breakpoint on it, but the program does not go into it

Draw so

```cpp
void MyItem::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget)
{
    painter->setBrush(myColor);
    painter->setPen(Qt::black);

    painter->drawRect(boundingRect());

    painter->drawText(QPointF(w / 2,h / 2),myStr);
}
```

For this I inherit from QIconEngine

```cpp
class MyIconEngine : public QIconEngine
{
public:
    MyIconEngine(MyItem* item);

    // QIconEngine interface
public:
    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QRect &rect, QIcon::Mode mode, QIcon::State state) override;
    QIconEngine *clone() const override;

private:
    MyItem* myItem;
};
```

Its implementation

```cpp
MyIconEngine::MyIconEngine(MyItem* item): myItem(item)
{}

void MyIconEngine::paint(QPainter *painter, const QRect &rect, QIcon::Mode mode, QIcon::State state)
{
    myItem->paint(painter,nullptr,nullptr);
}

QIconEngine *MyIconEngine::clone() const
{
    return new MyIconEngine(myItem);
}
```

Use thus

```cpp
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QListWidget* lw = new QListWidget();
    int w = 45;
    int h = 45;
    lw->setIconSize(QSize(w,h));

    MyItem* i1 = new MyItem(w,h,Qt::red,"red");
    MyItem* i2 = new MyItem(w,h,Qt::green,"green");
    MyItem* i3 = new MyItem(w,h,Qt::blue,"blue");

    MyIconEngine* ie1 = new MyIconEngine(i1);
    MyIconEngine* ie2 = new MyIconEngine(i2);
    MyIconEngine* ie3 = new MyIconEngine(i3);

    QIcon* icon1 = new QIcon(ie1);
    QIcon* icon2 = new QIcon(ie2);
    QIcon* icon3 = new QIcon(ie3);

    QListWidgetItem* lwi1 = new QListWidgetItem(*icon1,i1->Str(),lw);
    QListWidgetItem* lwi2 = new QListWidgetItem(*icon2,i2->Str(),lw);
    QListWidgetItem* lwi3 = new QListWidgetItem(*icon3,i3->Str(),lw);

    lw->show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

MyItem.h

```cpp
class MyItem : public QGraphicsItem
{
public:
    MyItem(int width,int height, const QColor& color,const QString& text);

    const QString& Str() const
    {
        return mySrt;
    }

    // QGraphicsItem interface
public:
    QRectF boundingRect() const override;
    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget) override;

private:

    QColor myColor;
    int w;
    int h;
    QString mySrt;
};
```

MyItem.cpp

```cpp
MyItem::MyItem(int width, int height, const QColor &color,const QString& text):w(width),h(height),myColor(color),mySrt(text)
{}

QRectF MyItem::boundingRect() const
{
    return QRectF(0,0,w,h);
}

void MyItem::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget)
{
    Q_UNUSED(option);
    Q_UNUSED(widget);

    painter->setBrush(myColor);
    painter->setPen(Qt::black);

    painter->drawRect(boundingRect());

    painter->drawText(QPointF(w / 2,h / 2),mySrt);
}
```

Comment: show the complete class `MyItem`

Comment: what is `Str()`

Comment: edited the question

Comment: The `MyIconEngine::paint` accepts `rect` as argument. All painting should be done within the `rect`. And you ignore it. You draw in local coordinates of the icon (`painter->drawRect(boundingRect());`). As an option, you could adjust the coordinate system of the `painter` before you pass it to the `myItem->paint(painter,nullptr,nullptr);`. Use `painter->translate(rect.topLeft());`.

Comment: @nicolai, you are partially right. The problem is indeed in `painter->drawRect(boundingRect());`. But the solution is to use `QStyleOptionGraphicsItem` instead of modifying the painter.

Comment: @scopchanov you are totally right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Cause

You draw the rectangle and the text in the wrong place:

```
painter->drawRect(boundingRect());
painter->drawText(QPointF(w / 2,h / 2),mySrt);
```

since you do not have information where to draw them.

And you do not have this information, because [QGraphicsItem::paint](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#paint) accepts a [QStyleOptionGraphicsItem](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleoptiongraphicsitem.html) as a second argument, but you pass a `nullptr` in your call:

```
myItem->paint(painter,nullptr,nullptr);
```

## Solution

Create an object of type `QStyleOptionGraphicsItem`, set it up and pass it to the `paint` method. Then use the passed information to draw with the `painter` in the correct places.

This will allow you to make further adjustments of how the decoration looks like, depending on the [QIcon::Mode](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qicon.html#Mode-enum) and [QIcon::State](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qicon.html#State-enum).

## Example

Here is a minimal example I have created for you in order to demonstrate how you could implement the proposed solution:

1. Change your implementation of `MyIconEngine::paint` like this:

   ```
   void MyIconEngine::paint(QPainter *painter, const QRect &rect, QIcon::Mode mode, QIcon::State state)
   {
       QStyleOptionGraphicsItem option;

       option.rect = rect;

       if (mode == QIcon::Selected)
           option.state = QStyle::State_Selected;

       myItem->paint(painter, &option, nullptr);
   }
   ```
2. Change your implementation of `MyItem::paint` like this:

   ```
   void MyItem::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget)
   {
       Q_UNUSED(option);
       Q_UNUSED(widget);

       painter->setBrush(myColor);
       painter->setPen(option->state == QStyle::State_Selected ? Qt::yellow : Qt::black);

       painter->drawRect(option->rect);
       painter->drawText(option->rect, mySrt, QTextOption(Qt::AlignCenter));
   }
   ```

I took the liberty to extend the example a bit further than what you have asked in order to show you why using `QStyleOptionGraphicsItem` is the right solution and how you can utilize it to achieve more.

This, i.e. `painter->drawText(option->rect, mySrt, QTextOption(Qt::AlignCenter));`, will fix the problem with the text positioning as well.

**Note:** This example is created for demonstration purposes. You might want to make further adjustments to `QStyleOptionGraphicsItem option` in order to make it suit the specific needs of your application.

## Result

As written, the given example produces the following result:

[image: Window with QListWidget with three custom decorated items]

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

```
QRectF MyItem::boundingRect() const
{
  return QRectF(0,0,w,h);
}
```

I believe you're painting all your blocks in the same upper left corner.